# Is it good practise to have separate projects for backend and frontend with Django?

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

I'm building a project with `Django Rest API` as **backend** and a separate Django server for serving web **frontend**.

For accessing API from frontend I'm planning to use **vanilla-JS**. In future, I have the plan to serve the API to `mobile apps` also. Is it a good move? any suggestions?

The site is to deal with user registration, sign-in and user-generated contents.

Are there any problems with Django as a separate frontend for Rest API?

Comment: I suppose it depends. Will you use django features for serving the frontend? Generally, you would want static frontend assets (html, css, js, images, etc) to be served by a static webserver. Something like NGINX, Apache, or a CDN, particularly if you will not use django's features (e.g. template engines) for generating the frontend assets. Even if you serve HTML through django templates, you still should serve static assets (images, css, etc) from a CDN or static webserver, not a Django server.

Comment: I'm planning to serve static files from AWS S3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any problems with Django as a separate frontend for Rest
> API?

No. There are no problems using this approach. I believe your approach will allow you to scale up and also ensure separation of concerns.

Since you have multiple types of clients (web, mobile), the Django Rest Framework project still only need to provide one API. This will save work on the backend side of things.

You can read up on [this blog](https://vsupalov.com/do-i-need-to-combine-django-with-vue-or-react/). Hope it helps clear any concerns you have

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to use django rest api and angular for front end.By using angular you can make your front end more interactive and good. using rest api is good thinking.
you can learn angular from any platform it is easy to learn.

Comment: What is wrong with his approach? The OP is asking about using Django and JS in two separate projects. Not about angular. This should be a comment not an answer

Comment: Yes but actually I have created django project as you said but when we use django to do most of work by using django and sometimes django failed to load css and js sometime

Comment: But here angular will handle frontend and django will handle backend